# C#: delete lines before and after specific line

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program in which I can delete part and keep rest. Below is my example

For instance, if have more than 1000 lines of code containing (connectionstrings)

```
<add name="Sales" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString= "server=myserver;database=Products;uid=salesUser;pwd=sellMoreProducts" />
<add name="NorthWind" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=.;database=NorthWind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

what I would like is to program is to have only names, so from the example I would get an output having

```
Sales
Northwind
```

and so on in a seperate file.

Can anyone help me how can I create a program for this.

Please let me know if this is an irrelevent post rather than degrading this post.

This program will just delete a word but not couple of words or lines before and after Sales or Northwind

```
string line = null;
string line_to_delete = "providerName";

   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Source path location"))
   {
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Destination path location"))
         {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
              if (String.Compare(line, line_to_delete) == 0)
              continue;
              writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
         }
   }
```

I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Give me more detail. do you want to suppress connectionstrings in your program or what?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use C# logic to determine whether the name of an XML element is to be saved to a separate file.  Is this correct?

Comment: @MSL I just wanted to delete all word before and after Sales and Northwind as per the example showed above. **Note:** there are more than 1000 lines containing such things.

Comment: @Hoffma No. From the file wanted to delete the lines of code but keeping  specific words. Please check my example

Answer (score 1):

So you want to want to separate names in your text string.

If all of your lines are xml, this is a function for you.

You should use

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

private void SeparateNames(string txt)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("yourfile.txt");

    foreach (var line in txt.Split('\r'))
    {
        XElement el = XElement.Parse(line);

        sw.WriteLine(el.Attribute("name").Value);
    }

    sw.Close();
}
```

In this function I split your text line by line and use xml reader to read the name attribute of each line and write (append) it into a file.

Comment: Question: If you run this what will be output?

Comment: And I am getting error: "Data at the root level is invalid." Also it deletes everything from my file.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your input file. My program works for your sample

Comment: `  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          SeparateNames("name");
        }

        public static void SeparateNames(string txt)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\1.xml");

            foreach (var line in txt.Split('\r'))
            {
                XElement el = XElement.Parse(line);

                sw.WriteLine(el.Attribute("name").Value);
            }

            sw.Close();
            
        }`

Comment: I assume this is how you are doing it.